# machine learning Algorithm to identify pattern

Tags: android, algorithm, machine-learning

I am trying to build a permission based analysis system to detect malicious applications on android.

I have a dataset of malicious applications and normal applications

```
AppName | Permission
--------+--------------
xxx     | INTERNET
xxx     | READ_PHONE_STATE
xxx     | READ_SMS
ccc     | INTERNET
ccc     | ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
```

Likewise, what I need is to identify patterns that may lead to malicious activity.

For example: if INTERNET AND READ_SMS it's malicious because from the algorithm I have identified that in malicious applications that pattern is more available than in the normal applications.

so please give me your inputs on algorithms to make this a success.

Comment: basically there are 2 approaches: either your algorithm will learn to detect the patterns (but for that it needs some feedback and a good characterization of the application) or it uses a model (just as the example you provide unless that it can be far more elaborate) to compute a global probability of "maliciousness" for the application.

Comment: what method you think i should go? i mean i can simply say if internet + read_sms then malicious. but there is no weight in there. that is why i think of using a algorithm to go with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest possible option is to build a Naive Bayes classifier, as it will build a conditional probabilities in forms of `P(malicious|INERNET,READ_SMS)`, and so not only will give you  a working algorithm, but some insight into what is really happening "inside". Of course there are dozens of more complex models out there, but it is way to broad question to answer it correctly. I would give NB a try, and if it fails, look for other **binary classifiers** like Neural Networks, Decision Trees, SVMs etc.

Comment: Thank you very much @lejlot. can you please tell me on what i could build this p(malicious|INTERNET,READ_SMS). is there any tool or i have to develop using a language

Comment: any library implementing Naive Bayes, there are dozens of them, just google it.

Comment: you are really a god..... thank you